# Is it possible to present a view controller with a tab bar that has no icon selected?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

My boss wants me to present a view controller when a tab bar is first presented. He wants the tab bar to have no icon or tab selected, with the user able to select a tab that then dismisses the view controller. Is this possible?

To my knowledge and research suggests that you must always have an icon selected when using a tab bar controller. Is that true?

Comment: You can always create your own tab bar controller

Comment: Yeah, but can it ever have no icons selected? I thought it always needed to have one tab selected...

Comment: Your controller your rules. You can do anything you want.